# firebase storage upload image from .net got permission denied

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is how I upload images from my .net app to firebase storage.

```
 var stream = File.Open(pictureBox1.ImageLocation, FileMode.Open);
    var task = new FirebaseStorage("xxxxxxxx.appspot.com")
             .Child("folder")
             .Child("myImageName.png")
             .PutAsync(stream);


 var downloadUrl = await task;
```

When I run my code, I got this error.

```
  Code: 403  
  Permission denied. Could not perform this operation
```

This is my configuration for Firebase Storage Rules,

```
   service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

It's ok when I change

```
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

to

```
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
```

But I want to upload my image using authentication.
I have generated a private key json file from firebase.
This is how I've tried so far.

```
   FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("generatedPrivateKey.json")
        });
```

But I can't find any documentation to use it properly.

Comment: have you found any solution to this?